XPath for colspan attribute values as browser understands them?
I have a HTML table with possibly malformed or missing or duplicated colspan values:


<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th> <th>B</th> <th>C</th> <th>D</th> <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th> <th>G</th> <th>H</th> <th>I</th> <th>J</th>
      <th>K</th> <th>L</th> <th>M</th> <th>N</th> <th>O</th>
      <th>P</th> <th>Q</th> <th>R</th> <th>S</th> <th>T</th>
      <th>U</th> <th>V</th> <th>W</th> <th>X</th> <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td                         >  0 </td>
      <td colspan=""              >  1 </td>
      <td colspan="0"             >  2 </td>
      <td colspan="2"             >  3 </td>
      <td colspan="-2"            >  4 </td>
      <td colspan="+ 2"           >  5 </td>
      <td colspan="+2"            >  6 </td>
      <td colspan="*2#%@!"        >  7 </td>
      <td colspan="2.7"           >  8 </td>
      <td colspan="-2.3"          >  9 </td>
      <td colspan="2e1"           > 10 </td>
      <td colspan=" 2 "           > 11 </td>
      <td colspan="2xx"           > 12 </td>
      <td colspan="2 3"           > 13 </td>
      <td colspan="2" colspan="3" > 14 </td>
      <td colspan="++2"           > 15 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



I would like to get the colspan value of each td as a HTML5 browser would "understand" them. I'm currently trying to figure out what the W3C specification says about it, but let's consider that the results displayed by running the above snippet are my expected output:



colspan
HTML5 value




missing
1


""
1


"0"
1


"2"
2


"-2"
1


"+ 2"
1


"+2"
2


"*2#%@!"
1


"2.7"
2


"-2.3"
1


"2e1"
2


" 2 "
2


"2xx"
2


"2 3"
2


"2" & "3"
2


"++2"
1



How can I achieve it using XPath 3.1?

I came up with this XPath expression:
//td/( (1, @colspan[. castable as xs:double]) => max() => xs:integer() )

But it has a few issues like converting "2e1" to 20 instead of 2.

Consider regex pattern matching on the space-normalized value to extract leading integer characters, ignoring all characters beginning with the first non-integer character.  Then successful match yields the leading integer; all else yields 1.

Consider regex pattern matching the value to extract leading digit characters, ignoring all characters beginning with the first non-digit character. Then successful match yields the leading integer; all else yields 1:
//td/(if (matches(@colspan[1],'^\s*\+?[1-9]\d*')) 
          then replace(@colspan[1], '^\s*\+?(\d+).*$', '$1') 
          else '1')

Update: Now handles question update that added cases, colspan="0" and colspan="+2".
Update 2: Added [1] to @colspan per Fravadona observation that (not-well-formed) HTML tables might have multiple @colspan attributes.

@Fravadona: Crazy that you'd encounter two @colspan attributes on the one element, but the real world can be messy.   Updated.

According to the W3C and WHATWG standards, a valid colspan value is, in regex terms, of the form ^\s*\+?(\d+).*, with the part in parentheses being the part to be converted into a base ten number. Both standards fallback to 1 when colspan is zero, invalid or missing.
@kjhughes answer works well enough but here's an other way with analyze-string and max:
//td/( max((1, analyze-string(@colspan[1], "^\s*\+?\d+")/fn:match)) )


ASIDE
Here are some relevant bits of the W3C standard:

Algorithm for processing rows:



If the current cell has a colspan attribute, then parse that attribute's value, and let colspan be the result.
If parsing that value failed, or returned zero, or if the attribute is absent, then let colspan be 1, instead.




Rules for parsing non-negative integers:



Skip whitespace.




If the character indicated by position is a U+002B PLUS SIGN character (+), advance position to the next character. (The "+" is ignored, but it is not conforming.)




Collect a sequence of characters in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0) to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), and interpret the resulting sequence as a base-ten integer. Let value be that integer.



Collect a sequence of characters


While position doesn't point past the end of input and the character at position is one of the characters, append that character to the end of result and advance position to the next character in input.


Nice and concise!  And great job with this Q/A overall.
